# iOS: Is [NSData writeToFile:atomically:YES] thread safe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, atomic, apfs

I'm trying to figure out what happens if I write to the same file using the method `[NSData writeToFile:atomically:YES]` from multiple threads. Is there a guarantee that the file will be uncorrupted after the threads finish writing to it?

For simplicity you can assume the file system is APFS (iOS 11+).

The question is also relevant for `NSFileManager`'s
`[replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:]`

Comment: Why would you write to a file using multiple threads anyway?

Comment: It is thread-safe, but you'll get only the contents of the last write. I don't see any practical use case where you would be concerned by thread safety in this case.

Comment: A possible scenario can be a network library that was requested to download the same file from two threads, and each thread copies the file to the same directory when it finishes. Of course, it is redundant to invoke the same request multiple times, but I don't want to assume that it won't happen.

Comment: If it's possible the multiple threads can write to the same file then you should provide functionality to manage it.  This would allow you to deny the action, for example, rather than trampling over another thread's data.

Comment: Thanks! Eventually I decided to go with your advice and manage it.